# SQL query with multiple CheckedListBox values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a database (MSSQL) driven c# winforms app, where I am trying to fetch data to a ListView based on user search. There are several CheckedListBoxes populated from the database specific columns (Enums). I know I should put the CheckedListBox values into a List<> and then add it to the sql parameter, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have in (OOP regarding) my databasemanager class:

```
public static List<Products> SearchProduct(int searchpartnumber, string searchdescription), int searchbrand, int searchcategory, int searchmarket, int searchfactory, int searchtype, int searchbarcode)
    {
        try
        {
            command.Connection = connection;                
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE part_number = @PARTNUMBER OR description = @DESCRIPTION OR brand = @BRAND OR category = @CATEGORY OR market = @MARKET OR factory = @FACTORY OR type = @TYPE OR bar_code = @BARCODE";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            SqlParameter querypartnumber = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@PARTNUMBER",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchpartnumber
            };

            SqlParameter querydescription = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@DESCRIPTION",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchdescription
            };

            SqlParameter querybrand = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@BRAND",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchbrand
            };

            SqlParameter querycategory = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@CATEGORY",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchcategory
            };

            SqlParameter querymarket = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@MARKET",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchmarket
            };

            SqlParameter queryfactory = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FACTORY",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchfactory
            };

            SqlParameter querytype = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@TYPE",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchtype
            };

            SqlParameter querybarcode = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@BARCODE",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = searchbarcode
            };

            command.Parameters.Add(querypartnumber);
            command.Parameters.Add(querydescription);
            command.Parameters.Add(querybrand);
            command.Parameters.Add(querycategory);
            command.Parameters.Add(querymarket);
            command.Parameters.Add(queryfactory);
            command.Parameters.Add(querytype);
            command.Parameters.Add(querybarcode);

            //Empty list
            for (int i = product.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                product.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            //Reading data
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                product.Add(new Products((int)reader["part_number"], reader["description"].ToString(), (Brands)(int)reader["brand"], (Markets)(int)reader["market"], (Factories)(int)reader["factory"], (Types)(int)reader["type"], (int)reader["bar_code"], (int)reader["width"], (int)reader["heigth"], (int)reader["length"], (int)reader["pieces"], (int)reader["temperature"]));
            }
            reader.Close();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            return product;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new DatabaseException("Unable to perform search!", ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

And here is what I have attached to the search button:

```
private void btn_ProductSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int searchpartnumber = (int)nud_PartNumber.Value;
        string searchdescription = tbx_Description.Text.Trim();
        try
        {
            int k = 1;
            lsv_Products.BeginUpdate();
            lsv_Products.Items.Clear();
            DatabaseManager.CreateProductSearchSql(searchpartnumber, searchdescription);

            foreach (var item in DatabaseManager.SearchProduct(searchpartnumber, searchdescription))
            {
                ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(k.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.PartNumber.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Description);
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Brand.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Market.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Factory.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Type.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.BarCode.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Width.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Height.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Length.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Pieces.ToString());
                row.SubItems.Add(item.Temperature.ToString());
                lsv_Products.Items.Add(row);
                k++;
            }
            lsv_Products.EndUpdate();
            lsv_Products.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is the problem in this sample?

Comment: So what issue specifically are you having?

Comment: I don't know who to pass the checkedlistbox values to the sql parameter. And make the sql query accepting null values meaning if some checkedlistbox for example have all the values checked.

Comment: Two concerns: does your query passed into the DB use wrapped paramertization? Are you using executesql to limit SQL injection? The latter should always be done, and the former is interesting since SQL Server initializes variables in a procedure at compile time. Meaning, it is like a temporary variable that is not yet called...it has no value to the SQL Optimizer at the time it is creating a plan. Things to mull on. (I had a query returning 1 row brought down the server when it zombied (500 queries). SQL Server will use the last query statistics to run queries with an unknown parameters)